# What is this matrix operator?

Tags: matrix-equations

What is the operator that can combine two 2x2 matrices into one 4x4 matrix as shown below?

A = $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$

X = $\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\z&w\end{bmatrix}$

A ? X = $\begin{bmatrix}aX&bX\\cX&dX\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}ax&ay&bx&by\\az&aw&bz&bw\\cx&cy&dx&dy\\cz&cw&dz&dw\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: This is called Kronecor Product or Direct product of two matrices. Seehttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). It's one manifestation of the tensor product from abstract algebra, and it's usually denoted by $\otimes$.